# expression(phantom() >= 1) not showing in base R plots

Tags: r, plot, expression, plotmath

Below, I wonder why the greater, equal sign doesn't show on my Base R plot?

```
plot(1)
legend("topright", expression(phantom() >= 1))
```

[image]

```
> sessionInfo()

R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] stats4    stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] bbmle_1.0.25       fastDummies_1.6.3  forcats_0.5.2      stringr_1.5.0     
 [5] dplyr_1.0.10       purrr_1.0.0        readr_2.1.3        tidyr_1.2.1       
 [9] tibble_3.1.8       ggplot2_3.4.0      tidyverse_1.3.2    emmeans_1.8.3     
[13] rlang_1.0.6        plotrix_3.8-2      lexicon_1.2.1      effects_4.2-2     
[17] carData_3.0-5      nlme_3.1-160       clubSandwich_0.5.8 metafor_3.8-1     
[21] metadat_1.2-0      Matrix_1.5-1      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] TH.data_1.1-1       googledrive_2.0.0   minqa_1.2.5         colorspace_2.0-3   
  [5] ellipsis_0.3.2      estimability_1.4.1  flextable_0.8.3     base64enc_0.1-3    
  [9] fs_1.5.2            rstudioapi_0.14     farver_2.1.1        lavaan_0.6-15      
 [13] bit64_4.0.5         fansi_1.0.3         mvtnorm_1.1-3       lubridate_1.9.0    
 [17] mathjaxr_1.6-0      xml2_1.3.3          codetools_0.2-18    splines_4.2.2      
 [21] mnormt_2.1.1        knitr_1.41          jsonlite_1.8.4      nloptr_2.0.3       
 [25] broom_1.0.2         dbplyr_2.2.1        compiler_4.2.2      httr_1.4.4         
 [29] backports_1.4.1     assertthat_0.2.1    fastmap_1.1.0       gargle_1.2.1       
 [33] survey_4.1-1        cli_3.5.0           htmltools_0.5.4     tools_4.2.2        
 [37] OpenMx_2.21.8       coda_0.19-4         gtable_0.3.1        glue_1.6.2         
 [41] Rcpp_1.0.9          cellranger_1.1.0    vctrs_0.5.1         insight_0.18.8     
 [45] xfun_0.36           rvest_1.0.3         lme4_1.1-31         timechange_0.1.1   
 [49] lifecycle_1.0.3     googlesheets4_1.0.1 MASS_7.3-58.1       zoo_1.8-11         
 [53] scales_1.2.1        vroom_1.6.0         hms_1.1.2           parallel_4.2.2     
 [57] sandwich_3.0-2      yaml_2.3.6          pbapply_1.6-0       gdtools_0.2.4      
 [61] bdsmatrix_1.3-6     stringi_1.7.8       boot_1.3-28         zip_2.2.2          
 [65] pkgconfig_2.0.3     systemfonts_1.0.4   evaluate_0.19       lattice_0.20-45    
 [69] labeling_0.4.2      bit_4.0.5           tidyselect_1.2.0    magrittr_2.0.3     
 [73] R6_2.5.1            generics_0.1.3      multcomp_1.4-20     DBI_1.1.3          
 [77] mgcv_1.8-41         withr_2.5.0         pillar_1.8.1        haven_2.5.1        
 [81] survival_3.4-0      nnet_7.3-18         crayon_1.5.2        modelr_0.1.10      
 [85] uuid_1.1-0          utf8_1.2.2          ellipse_0.4.3       tzdb_0.3.0         
 [89] rmarkdown_2.19      officer_0.5.1       syuzhet_1.0.6       grid_4.2.2         
 [93] readxl_1.4.1        data.table_1.14.6   pbivnorm_0.6.0      metaSEM_1.3.0      
 [97] reprex_2.0.2        digest_0.6.31       xtable_1.8-4        numDeriv_2016.8-1.1
[101] openssl_2.0.5       RcppParallel_5.1.7  munsell_0.5.0       mitools_2.4        
[105] askpass_1.1         quadprog_1.5-8
```

Comment: Works fine for me, add `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: Looks like a missing font issue. Which graphics device are you using? What is your OS?

Comment: @Roland, and  @jay.sf, added `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: Restart R and run the code without all these attached or loaded packages. Are you plotting to the RStudio device? (Also: You should update R.)